# Convert TRUE FALSE to 1 and 0 during export to Excel (from MS Access) through vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

While trying to export my tables from Access to Excel via `VB.NET`, I want TRUE and FALSE values to appear as 1s an 0s in my excel sheet. Below is my code to export and write the data in excel.

`If(.Cells(d, e).value = True, 1, 0)` throws an error '`conversion from type string to Boolean is not valid`'. I guess this is because I have 'string' data as well in my Access table. Can someone please help.

```
  Dim e As Integer = 1
            For col = 0 To ComDset2.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                d = 2
                For row = 0 To ComDset2.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                    .Cells(d, e).Value = ComDset2.Tables(0).Rows(row).ItemArray(col)
                    IIf(.Cells(d, e).value = True, 1, 0)

                    d += 1
                Next
                e += 1
            Next
```

Comment: The `IIf(.Cells(d, e).value = True, 1, 0)` line assumes that the Cell value is of `Boolean` type what is not the case (Excel cells are always `String`). The way to avoid this problem is either treating the cell as a string (`IIf(.Cells(d, e).value.ToString().ToLower() = "true", 1, 0)`) or converting the cell into `Boolean` (via `Convert.ToBoolean`, for example; although it would trigger an error for any non-boolean value, that is, anything different than `True`, `False` or `Integer`). Alternatively, you might rely on a different approach (as suggested via answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @varocarbas in the comment below your question, you will realise what the error in your code is.

> The IIf(.Cells(d, e).value = True, 1, 0) line assumes that the Cell value is of Boolean type what is not the case (Excel cells are always String). The way to avoid this problem is either treating the cell as a string (IIf(.Cells(d, e).value.ToString().ToLower() = "true", 1, 0)) or converting the cell into Boolean (via Convert.ToBoolean

However, instead of replacing that in the loop do it outside the loop in ONE GO.

**TRIED AND TESTED IN VB.NET 2010 + EXCEL 2010 (Sigh)**

```
 rng.Replace(What:="TRUE", Replacement:="1", LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, _
 SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
 ReplaceFormat:=False)

 rng.Replace(What:="FALSE", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, _
 SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
 ReplaceFormat:=False)
```

**More FollowUp from Comments**

See this example

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        '~~> Define your Excel Objects
        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsx")
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1)

        Dim i As Integer = 1
        Dim d As Integer = 0
        Dim startRow As Integer = 0

        With xlWorkSheet
            For col = 0 To ComDset2.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                d = 2
                startRow = d

                For Row = 0 To ComDset2.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                    .Cells(d, e).Value = ComDset2.Tables(0).Rows(Row).ItemArray(col)
                    d += 1
                Next

                '~~> Create your range here
                Dim rng As Excel.Range = .Range(.Cells(startRow, i), .Cells(d - 1, i))

                rng.Replace(What:="TRUE", Replacement:="1", LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False)

                i += 1
            Next
        End With

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @Siddharth. Thx for this. much appreciated. How do I convert it into VB.NET...is there any VBA to VB.NET converter ?

Comment: @Kashif77: It is A `VB.NET CODE`!

Comment: @SiddharthRout..sorry for my ignorance, but it shows an error 'Public member 'XLLookat' on type 'Application class' not found..

Comment: @Kashif77: How are you interacting with Excel? Have you declared `Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` at the top?

Comment: @SiddharthRout. Yes I have it referenced at the top...what is 'rng' in the code? Do I have to declare it . Because if I just write .Replace(What:="TRUE", Replacement:="1", LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False)

it doesn't throw error in VS but when I write it like 
rng.replace...
it shows an error in VS

Comment: @SiddharthRout. Thank you so much. your example code works for me finally..you saved me sir..thanks a million

Comment: OK. Let's delete everything.